# jQuery select2 not working when a valid JSON string is returned

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, jquery-select2

I am working on a project in CodeIgniter and had an issue when loading 25,000 rows into a select box (surprised eh?). So I wanted a select box that was searchable and loaded in a remote data set when a search query was typed in. I found this [library](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) called select2 and it seemed to be the solution to my problem.

However I cannot seem to get it to work even though I am returning a valid JSON string.

```
[{"Model_Name":"1340"},{"Model_Name":"1640"},{"Model_Name":"1645"},{"Model_Name":"1647"},{"Model_Name":"435MT"},{"Model_Name":"435T"},{"Model_Name":"7100"},{"Model_Name":"8000"},{"Model_Name":"8100"},{"Model_Name":"9000"},{"Model_Name":"9100"}]
```

Is there anything apparently wrong in the code below? My console.log is where the the string above is coming from.

```
 $("#part").select2({
ajax: {
  url: "home/populateModel/25",
  dataType: 'json',
  delay: 250,
  data: function (params) {
    return {
      q: params.term, // search term
      page: params.page
    };
  },
  processResults: function (data, params) {
    // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
    // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
    // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
    // scrolling can be used
    params.page = params.page || 1;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    return {
      results: JSON.stringify(data),
      pagination: {
        more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
      }
    };
  },
  cache: true
},
escapeMarkup: function (markup) { 
  //console.log(markup);
  return markup; 
}, // let our custom formatter work
minimumInputLength: 1
//templateResult: formatRepo, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
//templateSelection: formatRepoSelection // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
});
```

Comment: your json data format is not the same as in the examples should be something like [{id:1,text:"Text to display to user"},...], also "results: JSON.stringify(data)" is wrong because it converts your array into a string, if the server can preprocess the data in correct format as an array, then you can just have "results: data"

Comment: Thanks @vurentjie - another case of RTFM... I got it to return and display in the list and now I just need to get it to click and select. Turns out the format functions were omitted (as in the comments there) from the repo and needed to be re-created in my code. Thanks!